# Squash commits after rebase

Tags: git

I forgot to check the option `interactive` when rebasing a branch. I need one final commit but instead I have N commits on master. Is it possible to squash commits after the rebase process was finished?

Comment: What is the _virtual_ option? Which tool do you use? This does not seem like standard git cli.

Comment: @JohannesThorn, sorry, of course I meant `interactive`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can rebase them again. Use the following command for an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase --interactive <commit-id>
```

Where `<commit-id>` is the last commit you want unchanged. After that an editor will show up. Change all the `pick` commands to `squash` for the commits you want squashed into one.