# git squash commits after rebased with master branch?

Tags: git, github

let us suppose my branch is `featured-branch` in which i'm doing development

I rebased it with `master` with this some commits from mater comes in my branch

How can I squash only my commits to single one , so that when I raise a pull request only my changes should appear in that PR

but since other commits comes from master they have to be in my branch but not visible in the PR

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459116/squash-commits-after-rebase

Answer (score 2):

use `git rebase -i master` then editor will open change status of each commit with the following commands

```
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

For example

You rebase the master then run the command `git rebase -i master` after the you will see some commits (suppose) like this

```
pick cf2cf55 C-1: Added new commit
pick c7d2f77 C-3: Allow user
pick 7db9f8d C-5: added new commit
pick 2a2e8cf C-6: Removed quick edits
```

The format for the above content is `<command> <commit-id> <commit message>`.
Now you need to squash all commit into single commit then change pick command with your required command.

suppose we need to merge all commit into single commit then we use command `s` or `squash` like this

```
pick cf2cf55 C-1: Added new commit
s c7d2f77 C-3: Allow user
s 7db9f8d C-5: added new commit
s 2a2e8cf C-6: Removed quick edits
```

after save this. This will squash all other commits beside `C-1`. Now if you want to change commit messgae change it then save.

That's All.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to always deliver one commit without exposing internal development processes:

```
git checkout -b delivery origin/master
git merge --squash featured-branch
git commit -m "delivery message"
git push origin master
```